# How to finish door frame as thin as possible

Tags: drywall, door-frame, patching-drywall, frame, trim-carpentry

I was dumb and didn’t measure the laundry room entry way well enough and had to remove the molding to fit the units in.

In order to allow them to come out in the future I want to make the doorway as wide as possible. I tried doing thin drywall but it was too narrow of an entry way. I’m thinking just using drywall mud? And maybe some mesh wire? Any thoughts welcome!
[image]

Comment: Are you putting a door in?

Comment: I am not putting a door

Comment: How much space do you have between the jack studs, and how much space do you need to get the machines out?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't put drywall mud on the wood. The proper solution probably is to reframe the opening wider, it looks like there is at least 3 inches on the right hand side depending on how wide your casing is.

If you want something quick and easy and are fine with less than perfect finish, you could leave the rough framing exposed, cut the drywall back a little from the wood frame edge and either refinish the drywall with a profile to finish the rough drywall edge or install a small piece of trim about 1/2"x1/2" to cover the drywall edge, and then install your casing to that edge. Then paint and finish, you can use some wood filler to fix the rough framing a bit although it will likely never look perfect.

Answer (score 0):

A skim on framing lumber will never survive life.

A better strategy might be to attach a jamb with screws (and don’t hide the screw heads — just countersink them perfectly flush). You could use trim head screws if you wanted them less obvious.

Comment: Drywall joint compound on framing lumber _can_ indeed last. My living room coat closet says that it'll last about 20 years. Sure, it probably wasn't the ideal way of doing it, but I was 20-something and the internet wasn't around to tell me what I couldn't do or what I should do...

Comment: @FreeMan — I’m both impressed and surprised. Can you share details? (Type of mud, mesh tape or not, type of corners…)

Comment: @Freeman I have a special recipe, check my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

How to make DIY ultrathin "drywall":

Ingredients:

- [Fiberglass fabric](https://www.castorama.fr/fibre-de-verre-maille-tissage-a-peindre-plafond-diall-135g-m-l-25-m-vendu-au-rouleau-/3663602902584_CAFR.prd), the kind house flippers put on the walls to hide cracks. Sold in rolls. It's usually meant to be painted, but we won't be doing that. Get one without too much texture. This plays the part of the mesh wire you're suggesting, but it is much easier to smooth.
- Your choice of drywall mud or spackle of the easy to sand kind.
- [Universal primer](https://www.leroymerlin.fr/produits/revetement-sol-et-mur/papier-peint-frise-et-fibre-de-verre/colle-papier-peint/primaire-tous-supports-parexlanko-2l-03287-89177390.html) (product may depend on country, read instructions).

It turns out that drywall mud (at least the French ones) sticks extremely well to this particular universal primer. The primer is intended for thinset and self leveling compounds.

Pure plaster will not stick to this primer, but plaster-based compounds (like mud, spackle, etc) contain extra ingredients that make them stick to painted walls, which also work very well on primers. YMMV, but this essentially allows to coat anything the primer will stick to with plaster-based mud/spackle products that can then be sanded to a smooth finish.

Clean up the surface, maybe sand, depending on circumstances.

Apply one coat of mud.

Lay the fiberglass over the mud and smooth it with a spatula. As the mud is trapped between the fiberglass and the substrate, this hides all imperfections and creates a smooth finish. It works a lot better than the glue that is usually sold with these fiberglass rolls...

Apply another coat of mud. This makes a tough fiber-reinforced coat that won't flake off.

Wait for it to dry, then sand.